# Unable to add Azure Function as Stream Analytics Job output

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-stream-analytics

I am trying to add function as output to ASA job. I've read through all posts and suggestions I could find. Tried following:

- Added AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType with value 'Files' (tried lower case 'files' too)
- Lowered TLS version to 1.0
- Set function AuthorizationLevel to anonymous
- Tried App level and Fuction level keys
- Tested from Postman - always works correctly using POST method

But still get this error in job output ui (both manual and automatic output settings):

> System.InvalidOperationException: Runtime keys are stored on blob storage. This API doesn't support this configuration. Please change Environment variable AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType value to 'Files'. For more info, visit https://aka.ms/funcsecrets at Kudu.Core.Functions.FunctionManager.

With automatic settings (select Azure Function from subscription) I am getting 404 in function log:

> Outgoing response, type: response, statusCode: 404, statusText: NotFound

My function code:

```cs
public static class AsaRequestRouter {
        [FunctionName ("AsaRequestRouter")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run (
            [HttpTrigger (AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] 
            HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log) {                
            log.LogInformation ("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader (req.Body).ReadToEndAsync ();
            log.LogInformation(requestBody);
            return new OkObjectResult (@"{""response"":""OK""}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is strange. I know that Azure Function needs a Blob Storage attached to handle Queues and other stuff.
Maybe something got broken when you deployed your Azure function.

Check out this article, maybe it helps
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-with-azure-functions

It's based on Azure Function csx (cshap scripts), but it's similar to yours.

Comment: I started with this article. Maybe the difference is that my function app is hosted on a app service plan

Answer (score -1):

I faced a similar situation and ended up creating a *new* function app for my streaming analytics job that had only the azure function and the application setting `AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType with value 'Files'`.

Once the new function app is created, I got back to the Streaming Analytics job -> Outputs and tried to add an Azure Function as an output sink and provide details, there was a lag when Azure tries to display the function apps in your subscription. But once I selected my new function app, the error vanished.